# Why the color of vuetify v-chip not changing?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to use v-chip from vuetify but when I set the color, the color not changing, here is my code for the v-chip

here is how I import my vuetify

```
    import vuetify from 'vuetify';
    import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
    Vue.use(vuetify);
    
    const App = new Vue(Vue.util.extend({ router, Swal, vuetify : new vuetify() }, Template)).$mount('#app');
```

Here is how I call the v-chip

```
<v-data-table
:headers="headers"
:items="users"
:search="search"
>
    <template v-slot:[`item.status`]="{ item }">
        <v-chip
        color="red"
        >
        {{ getStatus(item.status) }}
        </v-chip>
    </template>
</v-data-table>
```

and here is the result

[image: v-chip color become light]

please help me

Comment: Strange. Can you share some of the code that contains the `v-chip` element?

Comment: @MattU okay, I have edit my code with the code contain the v-chip

Comment: Does it work if you use `primary` for the `color` attribute, or does nothing work at all?

Comment: @MattU primary also not working, there is primary color because I also use VueMaterial

Comment: @MattU I have edit my code again, adding how I import the vuetify, maybe I miss something when I import the vuetify?

Comment: Looks a bit odd. Take a look here: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/ roughly halfway down the page, where it talks about "create a plugin file for vuetify".

Comment: @MattU I have solve the problem, I forget to put <v-app> tag that is why it is not working. thank you for helping me :)